# Why does 1 out of 10 of my requests returns CORS error in the browser

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I currently have a script that makes an ajax request using `XMLHttpRequest()`. The essence of the script is to keep track of certain analytics and here's how it was implemented.

1. Adds an event listener and sends data to **start_tracking_analytics** script

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
try{
    
    //url to send data to
    var url = 'https://subdomain.domain.com/start_tracking_analytics.php?key='+tracker_key;
    
    //host name
    var host = location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname
    
    //send data
    sendAnalytics(url, host);
    
    
        setTimeout(function(){
            setInterval(function(){
                try{
                    sendUpdateAnalytics();
                }catch(e){
                    
                }
            }, 7500);
            
            
        }, 1000);
    
    }catch(e){
        
    }

});
```

2. Here's how the **sendAnalytics** function is implemented

```
function sendAnalytics(url, host){
    try{
        var createCORSRequest = function(method, url) {

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
        // Most browsers.
        xhr.open(method, url, true);

        } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {

        // IE8 & IE9
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);

        } else {

        // CORS not supported.
        xhr = null;
        }

        return xhr;

        };


        var method = 'POST';
        var xhr = createCORSRequest(method, url);
        
        xhr.onerror = function() {
        // Error code goes here.
        };

        xhr.send(); 
    }catch(e){
        //...
    }
}
```

3. Here's how **sendUpdateAnalytics** was implemented. **Note**: This gets triggered at intervals

```
 function sendUpdateAnalytics(){
    try{

        //url to send data to
        var url = 'https://subdomain.domain.com/end_tracking_analytics.php?id='+tracker_session_id; 
        
        //current host
        var host = location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname

        //send the data
        sendData(url, host);
    }catch(e){
        
    }   
}
```

**Now, to the backend (response) script. i.e - start_tracking_analytics.php && end_tracking_analytics.php**

On both scripts, I had this headers set

```
 //GET variables
$host = $_GET["host"];
$key = $_GET["key"];

//set header for CORS
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $host");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");

//I Do all of my computations here and echo an integer

echo 1;
```

**The problem**: 1 out of 10 requests made to `end_tracking_analytics` returns CORS error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://subdomain.domain.com/end_tracking_analytics.php?id=1&host=https://www.hostUrl.com&key=XXXXX' from origin 'https://www.hostUrl.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I really do hope this is explanatory and will be happy to provide more details if it's not. Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Are you sure that is only happening 1/10 times, or is your browser console grouping the messages that are the same?  If it is grouping them, there will be a # either on the left or right of the message, as your browser telling you how many times that message happened.

Comment: Looked through my console and it's made 30 HTTP calls with just 2 of those errors. I guess the idea is, I receive this CORS error every once in a while.

Comment: All to the same url?  Because if so that is very irregular behavior.

Comment: Yes, all to the same `https://subdomain.domain.com/end_tracking_analytics.php` URL. What would you suggest?

Comment: If you let the client to control the CORS header with GET parameter anyway then why wouldn't you just simply allow all hosts with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`?

Comment: Just use `fiddler` to see what was in the header, was it set at all and why was it blocked.

Comment: Hi @Adassko, the request is a `POST`. I had tried `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and ran into a problem. Besides, it'll be unsafe to allow all host to access this script

Comment: Okay @Adassko, I'll try out fiddler as suggested

Comment: You already allow all hosts to access this script by allowing to manipulate it with the host parameter. You should have the list of allowed origins on the server and set this header to request origin. Plus add "Vary: Origin" in the response to avoid caching problems

Comment: One more thing - you're showing a code that sends request to `end_tracking_data.php` and later you show error from `end_tracking_analytics.php`. Are these a typo or maybe you have mixed two different scripts?

Comment: Thanks for spotting that @Adassko. it happens to be a typo. I agree with your point on "manipulate the host's header" as equivalent to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`  Having a list of Origin makes sense but the list keeps growing as well, so might be really difficult and time-consuming to keep track. How would you suggest I add `"Vary: Origin"` to the response? - Not sure of the keyword

Comment: that's just another header - literally `header("Vary: Origin");`. From security point of view allowing client to change this header is equivalent to allowing all origins - attacker can put his code on his own website, simply change the "host" parameter and any user that will enter his website can automatically send a request in his name to your server. That's literally same level of security as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. I suggest verifying only the hostname, if the origin host matches to your allowed hosts list, then you just set CORS header to it

Comment: Thank you @Adassko. I'll try this out as well as your suggestion with the host and get back to you. Thanks